# База, указываемая для ES через ASSUME, почему-то применяется и к DS

Tags: ассемблер, masm

```
.386

Tabl1   struc          ; шаблон структуры
namex   db  8 dup(?)
field2  dw  ?
Tabl1   ENDS

Data1 segment use16    ; сегмент данных
I1  db  0
A1  Tabl1 6 dup(<>)
addres dd begin2
Data1   ENDS

code1 segment use16
assume cs:code1, ds:Data1
begin:
mov ax, Data1
mov ds, ax
mov di, 0
mov cx, 6
xor di, di
imul di, I1, 10   ; правильно ли заносить так индекс I1 в di?
xor ax, ax
   @go:
   mov A1[di].field2, offset A1[di].namex ; правильно так обращаться к массиву структур? 
   inc di
   loop @go

jmp dword ptr addres
;@a1:
    ;jmp far ptr @a

code1 ends
```

В сегменте кода `Code1` должно происходить следующее: в каждое поле `field2` структур из массива `А1` записать смещение в сегменте поля `namex` структуры с этим же индексом в массиве. Начальное значение индекса находится в байте за адресом `I1`.

Проблема в том, что в `ds` ничего не происходит, везде нули.

Comment: Лучше бы ответ написал, в чём ошибка была, чем удалять...

Comment: @Qwertiy ошибку я не могу найти, никто не отвечает

Comment: Ну может кто-нибудь ответит... Ассемблер - не самый популярный язык)

Comment: А зачем вы убрали хороший содержательный заголовок и поставили неинформативный? Мы не хотим, чтобы у нас на сайте были [сплошные заголовки "Помогите" или "проблема ассемблер"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6322/213987). Если вы сами не можете придумать точный заголовок -- то зачем мешать?